# USB drive's icon not appearing on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, icons, usb-storage, autorun

I have a USB flash drive for which I want to use a custom icon. My `autorun.inf` looks like this:

```
[Autorun]
UseAutoPlay=1
Label=TrueCrypt Traveler Disk
Icon=Volume.ico
Action=Start TrueCrypt Background Task
Open=TrueCrypt\Windows\TrueCrypt.exe
shell\start=Start TrueCrypt Background Task
shell\start\command=TrueCrypt\Windows\TrueCrypt.exe
shell\dismount=Dismount all TrueCrypt volumes
shell\dismount\command=TrueCrypt\Windows\TrueCrypt.exe /q /d
```

...but the icon doesn't appear, and nothing happens when I attach the drive - no dialog box, etc. I can still access it via "My Computer", but it doesn't have the icon. I've already set all options in the "AutoPlay" properties tab to "Prompt me each time to choose an action", but that doesn't fix anything.

I know this question has (probably) already been asked before, but the search feature gave me nothing. HOWEVER, this question is more centered on getting the icon working than getting auto-exec to work.

I'm running Windows XP Home Edition on this computer, but I will use it on Windows XP Professional and Windows 8 as well.

Comment: This might be obvious, but have you checked that the icon name is spelled correctly, and to include the full path to it? With the current configuration, the icon should be in the main USB folder, is it there?

Comment: @Sekhemty Yep - it's in the correct directory - Ubuntu recognizes it...

Comment: Please explain it: how Ubuntu recognizes it? These `autorun.inf` settings, AFAIK, will only work on Windows. Do you mean that you can open the `.ico` file with an image viewer?

Comment: @Sekhemty Ya, Ubuntu is designed to be as user-friendly as possible, so the developers added support for autorun.inf icons. I plugged it into the Ubuntu machine to perform a sanity check - making sure the icon is in the correct folder, double-checking autorun.inf's syntax, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the system attribute of the autorun.inf file. You'll need to set the system attribute from the commandline using something like:

```
attrib +S e:\autorun.inf
```